# Using Unit test with IllRepack Plugin D365

Tags: c#, unit-testing, plugins, dependencies, dynamics-crm

I Would like to know how can i test my plugin in local?

To help me I using this link [Write Unit Test for your Dataverse Plugins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70Og4JQ5MWQ)

In my case have some dependeces that main project plugin

The unit test:

```
namespace CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [Description("Teste Template ")]
        [Owner("Alexandre")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

            // init

            XrmFakedContext fakecontext = new XrmFakedContext();
            XrmFakedPluginExecutionContext pluginContext = fakecontext.GetDefaultPluginContext();
            XrmFakedTracingService iTracing = new XrmFakedTracingService();
            //Prepare

            Entity target = new Entity("Contact") { Id = id };
            target.Attributes.Add("telephone1","90381290381  8876");

            Entity postimage = new Entity("Contact") { Id = id };
            postimage.Attributes.Add("telephone1", "90381290381  88763232");

            ParameterCollection inputParameter = new ParameterCollection();
            inputParameter.Add("Target", target);

            EntityImageCollection postImages = new EntityImageCollection();
            postImages.Add("PostImage", postimage);
 


            pluginContext.InputParameters = inputParameter;
            pluginContext.PostEntityImages = postImages;

            fakecontext.Initialize(new List<Entity>() { postimage });


            //Execute
            fakecontext.ExecutePluginWith<PreOperationFormatPhoneCreateUpdate>(pluginContext);


            //Assert
            Entity teste = fakecontext.CreateQuery("Contact").FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.Equals("903812903818876", teste["telephone1"]);

            iTracing.Trace("Tested Trace in Account Create");

        
        }
    }
}
```

The main class of plugin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Comum;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository.Repository;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository.Repository.Interface;

namespace CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Service
{
    public class PreOperationFormatPhoneCreateUpdate : BasePlugin
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCrmPlugin(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            IContactRepository _contactRepository = new ContactRepository();
            _contactRepository.formatarTelefone(context);

        }
    }
}
```

the base of plugin

```
namespace CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Comum
{
    public abstract class BasePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public  IPluginExecutionContext localContext { get; set; }
        public IOrganizationService OrganizationService { get; private set; }
        public  void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("serviceProvider");
            }

            try
            {
                localContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
                if (!localContext.InputParameters.ContainsKey("Target"))

                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("No target found");

                IOrganizationService service = ((IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory))).CreateOrganizationService(null);

                ExecuteCrmPlugin(localContext, service);

               


            }
            catch (InvalidPluginExecutionException e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void ExecuteCrmPlugin(IPluginExecutionContext localcontext, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            // Implementar o código do Plugin no proprio Plugin 
        }
    }

}
```

The Repository Project

```
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Domain.Domain;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Factory.Factory;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository.Comum;
using CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository.Repository.Interface;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository.Repository
{
    public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
    {

        public Entity formatarTelefone(IPluginExecutionContext context)
        {

            Entity entity2 = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

            Contact contato = new ContactFactory().d365ToObject(entity2);

            contato.TelefoneComercial = Regex.Replace(contato.TelefoneComercial, @"[^\d]", "");

            return new ContactFactory().objectToD365(contato);

        }

    }
}
```

The struture of my solution

[Image Struture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELlvv.png)

[Image Struture 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHOtp.png)

[Dependences main plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJAic.png)

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkEqO.png)

Translate error

System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CRM.CLIENTE.Plugin.Repository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strong-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)'

SO someone help me about this problem ?

I want use unit test to validate my plugin in local

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin library is signed, because this is what is required by Dataverse.

As a consequence the projects your plugin project references must also be signed and this is also true for your test project.

Best practice is sharing one snk file and reference it from your projects. A quick fix is adding this snippet to the csproj files:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\CompanyKey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```